# Is there a ruby method for finding a blob uri?

Tags: ruby, sdk, azure-blob-storage

I checked the whole `azure-storage-blob` gem and didn't find any way to get the `URI` for a blob. Is there some way to construct it correctly and in a generic way that will work for any other blob in any region?

I used S3 SDK before and I'm well grounded in S3 but new to Azure.

Comment: You should use an Azure SDK. I found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby) a Ruby version.

Comment: @JeroenHeier the gem the OP is using is an official azure repo for storage management. The ARM sdk will not help in this case

Answer (score 1):

There is a protected method called [`blob_uri`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-ruby/blob/master/blob/lib/azure/storage/blob/blob_service.rb#L607)  that looks like this:

```
def blob_uri(container_name, blob_name, query = {}, options = {})
  if container_name.nil? || container_name.empty?
    path = blob_name
  else
    path = ::File.join(container_name, blob_name)
  end
  options = { encode: true }.merge(options)
  generate_uri(path, query, options)
end
```

So you could take the short cut of:

```
blob_client = Azure::Storage::Blob::BlobService.create(storage_account_name: 'XXX' , storage_access_key: 'XXX')
blob_client.send(:blob_uri, container_name,blob_name)
```

However, the actual URI is simply:

```
https://[storage_account_name].blob.core.windows.net/container/[container[s]]/[blob file name]
```

So since you have to know the blob name and the container to access to blob.

```
File.join(blob_client.host,container,blob_name)
```

Is the URI to the blob